# Pointer dereferencing

Tags: c++

```
char *m_chString="asd"; 
cout<<m_chString;//prints asd
cout<<*m_chString;//prints a


int nValue = 7;
int *pnPtr = &nValue;
cout<<*pnPtr;//prints 7
cout<<pnPtr;//prints the address of nValue
```

I gave two examples, in the first the pointer points to a string, and in the second, the pointer prints to an int value.
My question is, why `cout<<m_chString;` from the first example doesn't print the address of my string as it would do in the second example if I were to print `pnPtr` without dereferencing it?
Doesn't `pnPtr` point to an address?

Comment: There is a special `ostream& operator<<` overload that treats `char*` as a pointer to a null-terminated string.

Comment: Because `std::ostream &operator <<` is overloaded for `char*`

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: I'm not trying to print its address, I am trying to understand why it behaves like that.

Comment: because there is a special `ostream& operator<<` overload that treats `char*` as a pointer to a null-terminated string ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for that is that std::cout will treat a char * as a pointer to (the first character of) a C-style string and print it as such.

You can print the address by:-

```
    cout << (void *) m_chString;
```

OR if you are great C++ fan then

```
    cout << static_cast <const void *> (m_chString);
```

Comment: +1 since the general idea is right, but you might want to clarify that it's not `std::cout` itself doing this. It's the overload of `operator<<` which works for all output streams, not just `cout`.

Comment: If it points to the first character, then why doesn't it print only that one and it prints the whole string?

Comment: @Angew yes agree with you.

Comment: @GeorgeIrimiciuc Please see Angew's explanation.

Comment: @GeorgeIrimiciuc Because whoever designed the streams library decided it was more useful to treat `char*` as a pointer to a null-terminated string and print the whole string.

Comment: @GeorgeIrimiciuc Bracketing in the sentence. It treats it as a pointer to the first character of (a C-style string and prints it as such). Simply put: it's designed for printing strings.

Comment: I see. The thing is if I do `cout<<&m_chString;` it will print the address, too. Why do I need to cast it to void*, then?

Comment: @GeorgeIrimiciuc: With `cout<<&m_chString;`, you're printing the address of the pointer, which is completely different from the value of the pointer (that is, the address of the thing the pointer points to). If you print both `&m_chString` and `(void*)m_chString`, you should see different values.